# New S3 object equivalent to dataframe: why different print output?

Tags: r, class, dataframe, oop

I have recently started to learn OOP from Hadley Wickham's book.
I am trying to create a "new.data.frame" class that should have the same attributes as the existing "data.frame" one:

```
new_data.frame <- function(x, row.names = NULL, n){
  stopifnot(is.list(x))
  row.names <- .set_row_names(n)
  structure(x,
            row.names = row.names,
            class = "new.data.frame")

}
```

When I convert a random list into a "new.data.frame" object and print, I obtain this result:

```
a <- list(a = c(1,2), b = c(1,2), c = c(1,2))

a <- new_data.frame(a)

a

$a
[1] 1 2

$b
[1] 1 2

$c
[1] 1 2

attr(,"row.names")
[1] 1 2
attr(,"class")
[1] "new.data.frame"
```

If I do the same for the equivalent data.frame object I obtain:

```
data.frame(list(a = c(1,2), b = c(1,2), c = c(1,2))

  a b c
1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2
```

Why is this the case? Is it related to the method of the print function? 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have to point out, stylistically, that it seems really terrible to use both `new_data.frame` and `new.data.frame`.

Comment: Yes, you are totally right. I was just practising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is this the case? Is it related to the method of the print function?

Yes, data frames have a dedicated print method, `print.data.frame`. You `new.data.frame` class does not have a dedicated print method, so `print.default` is used.

If you want to leverage existing `data.frame` methods with you new class, you should *extend* the data frame class rather than creating a brand new class. You can do this by making the class attribute a vector, `class = c("new.data.frame", "data.frame")`. In this way, you can write custom methods that will be used when present, but if no custom method is present any `data.frame` methods will be used as a fallback.